# How can I say that I perfectly know a subject even because it is not a very broad one?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

There are two subjects, one is very broad and the other is not so broad, I would say for example that the Italian grammar is a subject wider than the English grammar.

What is an idiomatic expression to say that ones perfectly masters and knows a subject even because it is not wide?

It seems to me there should be a phrase with "head" but I cannot find it (something like "it fits in my head").

Comment: Are you sure it was "head"? There is an expression [know it like the back of one's **hand**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/know+like+the+back+of+one's+hand) *I've read this book so many times, I know it like the back of my hand.* That doesn't have anything to do with how extensive a topic is though, so I don't think it is the one you're looking for.

Comment: You can also [have a head for something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+head+for+(something)), but that means you have a natural talent for it, not that you know everything about it.

Comment: Does anyone know everything about a topic anyways? I wouldn’t say this because you will probably come off as arrogant.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I mean subject that have a limited scope, actually I was thinking of programming languages. One programming language is described in an ISO standard document of 100 pages, a second one in a document of 10000 pages.